# How to keep the background color persistent in css active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image, when user clicks on it I am changing the background color of it. for ex:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/image1.png" />
```

CSS:

```
img:active{
    background-color:red;
}
```

But the red color is not persistent. and the red color is replaced with the old color. How can I make it persistent ?

Comment: `:active` is defined as follows: _“The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.”_ – so this is not what you want. You will have to set a class or something else to make this state of the image discernible from its normal state for CSS.

Comment: read about [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event. `active` works when you only click.

Answer (score 1):

OnClick functionality isn't achievable solely through CSS.  You will need to use javascript to  achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

then in css make sure you have something like this:

```
img.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you should use javascript with `onclick` event handler, save the clicked element's state and toggle at right time... However I would like to introduce this work-around without using any script, it uses some focusable wrapper (like a `button`) to mimic other unfocusable element (like the `image`) and use the `:focus` pseudo-class to style the *active* element (as you understand, it can be in such a state by clicking or tabbing):

**HTML**:

```
<button class="wrapper">
  <img/>
</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.wrapper > img {
   background-color:inherit;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;        
}
.wrapper {
   border:none;
   padding:0;
   cursor:default;
}
.wrapper:focus {
   background-color:red;
   outline:none;
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swKyX/10/), try clicking the image and then clicking on some point outside to see it in action.